# Scale image properly (e.g. css-grid, flexbox), s.t. it fills available space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a image and some description text for the image below.
I want the image to take up as much as space as it needs to use the complete width of the div, but not more than there is space available. 
If there is remaining vertical space, it should remain at the bottom.

I have attempted this with flexbox:

```css
#image{
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;

    flex-grow: 99;
    flex-shrink: 99;
}

#flex-box{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: stretch;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex-box">
    <img id="image" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/angular-material-logo.svg">
  <h1>A header</h1>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
  <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

The problems are:

- A scrollbar appears, because the screen is exceeded vertically, which
  is not desired.
- Additionally, the image does only scale down, but not up.

Another attempt with css-grid was the following:

```css
#images {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto auto auto;
  text-align: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

#image-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div id="image-container">
    <img id="image" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/angular-material-logo.svg">
  </div>
  <h1>A header</h1>
  <p>A parapraph</p>

  <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

The problems here are:

- The image is again not scaled upwards.
- The content is stretched vertically across the screen.

What would be necessary to achieve the properties?

Comment: can you explain: *it should remain at the bottom* ?

Comment: Theres the picture. It takes up a certain amount of space of the screen. This space is limited in height as the picture cannot get infinitely high as the width of the image ist constrained. Then the there are the text elements. Depending on the width of the screen they also take up some space, but a finite amount, too. In summary you have a finite amount of space taken. It can be that the vertical space available is greater than the amount of space taken. The remaining space then should then be at the bottom of the screen, i.e. below the text (and not between text and image or image and top)

Answer (score 0):

On the image you can play around using max-width and adjusting the height:

```
#image {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 50vh;
}
```

Max width stops the image for expanding more than its container and set a max height for it to scale accordingly. VH is based on the height of the screen if you want to avoid a vertical scroll.

Comment: While this might work in most cases, often it does not. Especially, if the text heights change with varying screen widths (which happens when the paragraphs break lines - Ill add longer paragraphs)

Comment: Then you may need to also set a max-height on the text container and use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

Comment: This hides part of my text. I would like not to do that, but rather shrink the image.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using bootstrap 4 then below code can help you without using any custom css classes. All is to use bootstrap built in classes and it will automatically adjust contents.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>Bootstrap Template</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col border"> <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/angular-material-logo.svg" class="img-fluid">
                <h1 class="text-center">A header</h1>
                <p class="text-center">A paragraph</p>
                <p class="text-center">Another paragraph</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col border text-center align-self-center">
                <h2>AA</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col border text-center align-self-center">
                <h2>BB</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center border">
                <h2>B</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col border text-center align-self-center">
                <h2>C</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint to bootstraph. Unfortunately your solution does not implement the desired behavior: If I remove the two columns, the image is scaled up to the width of the screen. This results in a height that is too high: The text and paragraphs make the outer div/screen overflow which results in a scrollbar.